# How does recursive method to count white spaces in a string work?

Tags: java, oop, recursion

I'm trying to fully understand how the method works, see the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countspaces("a number of spaces "));
}

public static int countspaces(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0) + countspaces(s.substring(1));
}
```

I've debugged the method using BlueJ. The line:

```
return (s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0) + countspaces(s.substring(1));
```

firstly checks if the character at the index zero is a white space, then it calls itself again (this makes it recursive) taking the substring of s starting at index 1 as an argument effectively changing the argument from "a number of spaces " to " number of spaces " and doing it till the argument's length() reaches 0. What I don't get is why it's not returning 01000000100100000010 (the last 0 being for the empty string s which terminates the loop) but 4? I can't see where in the code it sums up the 1's returned by

```
(s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0)
```

and ignoring the 0's.
Please advise me what is missing from my reasoning.

Many Thanks

Grzegorz(Greg)

Comment: That would be the `+`.

Comment: Adding 0 to the sum doesn't change it

Comment: + here in numeric addition, not string concatination, e.g. 1+1 == 2, not 1+1 == 11.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you count spaces with recursion? Is this an assignment of some type?

Comment: Yeap,as a part of exam preparation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the method returns an int, not a string, it adds the numbers, not concatenates as characters/strings. ie

```
0+1+0+0+0+0+0+0+1+0+0+1+0+0+0+0+0+0+1+0 == 4
```

not

```
"0"+"1"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"1"+"0"+"0"+"1"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"0"+"1"+"0" 
== "01000000100100000010"
```

below returns an int, since countspaces returns an int

```
return (s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0) + countspaces(s.substring(1));
```

Comment: Thanks Vixen, that makes a perfect sense now!

Answer (score 2):

```
(s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0) + countspaces(s.substring(1))
```

This one basically sums up the `0`s and `1`s.

Take note of the return value of the method which is an `int`. The return value of `4` is perfectly fine.

To put in other words:

> 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0
>   + 1 + 0 = 4

Comment: Thanks Adam, what I missed is the return type in an int not a string of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to write the function in "English" in case that helps you understand it:

```
int countspaces( string ) {

    if string has no characters {
        return 0
    }
    else {

        if first character in string is a space 

        add 1 

        otherwise

        add 0

        to result of countspaces( string_with_first_character_removed )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of recursion is that the function is called over and over again, you could roughly say it's some sort of loop.

```
if (s.length() == 0)
    return 0;
```

This code is stopping condition (because the recursion stops at this point) of your recursive function, it will return 0 when the length of provided string is 0. Nothing much to explain here, I think that is pretty obvious.

And this part is core part of your recursive function:

```
return (s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0) + countspaces(s.substring(1));
```

`s.charAt(0) == ' ' ? 1 : 0` uses a [*ternary operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Usage), it checks if the first character in string is space, if it's true it uses value of 1, else it uses 0.

`countspaces(s.substring(1))` calls the function again, with substring that removes first character.

Function returns `int` value of 0 or 1, it sums the values returned, and as you know, `x + 0 = x`, so only the cases where first character is space (function returns 1) affect your final result.

This calls occurs until the function passes itself empty string, when it hits the *stopping condition*, where it goes back through the call stack, summing returned values and values from ternary operator and finally returns the expected result.